# syntax error in conditional expression while executing the shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk, wget

I am working on a project in which I need to make a url call to one of my server from the bash shell script..

```
http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat
```

After hitting the above url, I will be getting the below response which I need to parse it and extract value of `syncs` and `syncs_behind`

```
state: READY num_retries_allowed: 3 syncs: 30 syncs_behind: 100 num_rounds: 60 hour_col: 2 day_col: 0 oldest_day_col: 0
```

Now I need to hit the above url every 10 seconds for a period of 10 minutes and extract the value of `syncs` and `syncs_behind` from it and use to validate it with below condition -

```
syncs > 8
syncs_behind = 0
```

if the syncs is greater than 8 and syncs_behind = 0, then I will end my shell script with some message saying - "Data has been validated", otherwise I would keep on trying for 10 minute window.. If in that 10 minute window, this doesn't happen I will end the shell script anyway meaning I won't retry again.

So I started with the below code and I saved the file as `beat.sh` with the below contents –

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=60   #number of 10 second timeouts in 10 minutes
SUM_SYNCS=0
SUM_SYNCS_BEHIND=0

while [[ $COUNT -ge "0" ]]; do

#send the request, put response in variable
DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat)

#grep $DATA for syncs and syncs_behind
SYNCS=$(echo $DATA | grep -o 'syncs: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')
SYNCS_BEHIND=$(echo $DATA | grep -o 'syncs_behind: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')
echo $SYNCS
echo $SYNCS_BEHIND

#add new values to the sum totals
let SUM_SYNCS+=SYNCS
let SUM_SYNCS_BEHIND+=SYNCS_BEHIND

#verify conditionals
if [[ $SYNCS -gt "8" -a $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq "0" ]]; then exit -1; fi

#decrement the counter
let COUNT-=1

#wait another 10 seconds
sleep 10

done
```

And when I am running it as `./beat.sh`, I got below error -

```
./beat.sh: line 23: syntax error in conditional expression
./beat.sh: line 23: syntax error near `-a'
./beat.sh: line 23: `if [[ $SYNCS -gt "8" -a $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq "0" ]]; then exit -1; fi'
```

Any thoughts what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Is the double colon `grep -o 'syncs:: [0-9]+'` correct?

Comment: @Hauke:no its not correct.. that's by mistake I have updated that.. Thanks for pointing out..

Comment: And somehow my echo statements are not getting printed out at all.. Not sure what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash's `[[` does not support `-a`.  One approach is to use `[` and otherwise keep things the same:

```
[ $SYNCS -gt "8" -a $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq "0" ]
```

For best results with `[`, though, one should double-quote variables:

```
[ "$SYNCS" -gt 8 -a "$SYNCS_BEHIND" -eq 0 ]
```

In the general case though `-a` and `-o` should be avoided as the `[` command [cannot parse its arguments reliably when it receives more than 4 (beside `[` and `]`)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16). So

```
[ "$SYNCS" -gt 8 ] && [ "$SYNCS_BEHIND" -eq 0 ]
```

**Alternatively**, keep the `[[` but use `&&` for `-a`:

```
[[ $SYNCS -gt "8" && $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq "0" ]]
```

Many people prefer `[[` over `[` because the double-quotes around variables are unnecessary.

But here, if you're going to use ksh/bash/zsh specific syntax, for arithmetic comparison, you might as well write it:

```
(( SYNCS > 8 && SYNCS_BEHIND == 0 ))
```

**MORE:**  The `grep` lines have two issues.  As Hauke pointed out, there is a superfluous colon in one.  Second, to use the `[0-9]+` syntax, both lines need  the `-E` option for extended regex:

```
SYNCS=$(echo "$DATA" | grep -oE 'syncs: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')
SYNCS_BEHIND=$(echo "$DATA" | grep -oE 'syncs_behind: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Thanks John.. This worked now.. I am able to run it atleast.. But somehow my echo statements are not printing out anything. `echo $SYNCS  echo $SYNCS_BEHIND` not sure what could be wrong.. Any thoughts? I can see DATA getting printed out..

Comment: @Webby That the `echo` commands didn't print anything was a sign that the `grep`s failed to match.  See updated answer.

Comment: Yeah now it works fine.. Can you explain what does E do here?

Comment: @Webby it tells grep to use ERE instead of BRE regex.

Comment: `-E` is obviously not needed for `[0-9]`. It is needed for `+`. Without `-E` `\+` would be necessary instead.

Comment: @John1024 One quick question. It's an old post but you might be able to help me out on this. Currently If you see my shell script above, I am exiting out using `exit -1` which is not a successfull exit. Am I correct? If I need to exit out of the shell script successfully then I should use `exit 0`.?

Comment: @Webby  Yes `exit 0` for success.  Any nonzero number, including -1, signals failure.